# sort date column on click in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I tried to sort different columns of a table using angular js functionality sort.

```
$scope.sort = function (column) {
        if ($scope.orderProp === column) {
            $scope.direction = !$scope.direction;
        } else {
            $scope.orderProp = column;
            $scope.direction = false;
        }
    }
```

I have written above code, it is working properly for alphabate values of coulmn but not working properly for start date column..

Comment: Initializations $scope.orderProp = 'srNo';
  $scope.direction = true;

Comment: please make sure date is always in similar format, can you give jsfilddle example check jsfiddle working properly http://jsfiddle.net/HrGdt/29/